# Unable to insert entity using room

Tags: android-room, viewmodel, dao

I am new to android Room and trying to insert some one-to-many relationships into my database. But I am facing some issues that I have not managed to fix sofar.
Here is my data constellation:

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "artist")
data class Artist(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
   val name: String,
) {
}

@Entity(
tableName = "song",
foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = Artist::class,
    parentColumns = ["id"],
    childColumns = ["artistId"],
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)]
)
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    val artistId: Long,
    val title: String?
) {
}

data class ArtistWithSongs(
@Embedded val artist: Artist,
@Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "artistId", ) val songs: List<Meal>
) {
}
```

Repository:

```
@Singleton
class AppRepository @Inject constructor(
private val artistDao: ArtistDao
) {

suspend fun insert(artist: Artist) {
    artistDao.insert(artist)
 }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ArtistDao {
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   suspend fun insert(artist: Artist)
}
```

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ArtistViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val repository: AppRepository,
  private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

fun insert(artist: Artist) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insert(artist)
}
}
```

Then in my activity I call:

```
private val viewModel: ArtistViewModel by viewModels()
```

...

```
val artist = Artist("Bob")
viewModel.insert(artist)
```

But insert artist does not work. The database is still empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using `viewModel.artist.value` to check if any artist was present. As the method returning artist has `LiveData` as return type, I was getting null.
Observing the artist instead proved that my insert method is working just right.